# UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI field not visible in data loader

Tags: soql, data-loader

I can run soql query as below, but cannot find `UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI` in data loader. Is their another field i can use in data loader for this purpose?

```
Select Id, UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI, Username, Name FROM User
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing research found out, that you have to go to **Salesforce 1 settings** and enable **"Enable the Salesforce 1 browser App"**

Also make sure you are using Data loader v29 or later. Restart data loader and you will see "UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI" field.